# Sending object from mongoDB to client socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I need help displaying object properties on client side

server

```
socket.on('question', (data) => {
  Question.count().exec((err, count) => {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    Question.findOne().skip(random).exec(
      function(err, data) {
        socket.emit('data', {
          question: data.question,
          correctAnswer: data.correct_answer,
          incorrectAnswer1: data.incorrect_answers[0],
          incorrectAnswer2: data.incorrect_answers[1],
          incorrectAnswer3: data.incorrect_answers[2]
        });
      });
  });
});
```

client

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  if (data) {
    $('#questions').html('');
    $('#questions').append('<li>' + question + '</li>')
  }
});

$('#answer').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('question', {'data':$(this).serializeArray()});
});
```

[image: I only get displayed this]

I only get displayed this

I want to display question and answers underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get your data inside your `data` variable. So every information your need are stored inside.
Use `console.log(data)` to see what's inside. Always show the content you get.

I don't know how you build your question object, but something like that should work

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  if (data) {
    $('#questions').html('');
    $('#questions').append('<li>' + data.title + '</li>')
  }
});
```

Comment: This adds undefined, console log on server prints object.

Comment: do a console.log on your client side.

Comment: ok tnx this works. It stores data in another data object, i don't know why. @sheplu